# What's the purpose of the cmd column in the sp_who stored procedure result set?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

When executing sp_who I get this

[image]

I want to know what's the purpose of cmd column. What parameter does it represent?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [sp_who (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> ```
> ╔════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
> ║ Column ║ Data type ║                    Description                    ║
> ╠════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
> ║ cmd    ║ nchar(16) ║ Database Engine command ( Transact-SQL statement, ║
> ║        ║           ║ internal Database Engine process, and so on)      ║
> ║        ║           ║ executing for the process.                        ║
> ╚════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
> ```